# glCompileShader crashes on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to use a fragment shader on a Galaxy tab 10.1 device, and it just crashes inside my call to glCompileShader.
I'm using OpenGL ES 2. 
The shader source code is a little bit lengthy (70 lines... no that much), but I know it is not too long because if I just change the last line to return a constant color

```
void main(void) 
{
   float r, g, b; 
   ... // Code to compute values for r,g,b 
   gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0); line to be replaced
}
```

by

```
 gl_FragColor=vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

the shader works perfectly.

Also, the unmodified version of the shader works perfectly on a Samsung Galaxy S.

If it was giving some compilation error, I would know what is wrong, but just crashing while compiling: it is confusing.

Thanks for your help.

Edit.:
By replacing the line, all the remaining of the shader code gets optimized and is probably removed by the compiler. So the crash is probably caused by some other line of code being compiled... But crashing... Anyone experienced that before?

Comment: Can you post what the last line is when the compile crashes (the line you change to make it work)?

Comment: Thank you Jave, I didn't knew that tool. It could be very helpful.
But the problem in this case, is that the exact same shader compiles and executes and does the right effect on another device (Galaxy S), but the shader compiler crashes with it on the Galaxy Tab 10.1.

Got any idea on why?

Comment: Possibly a hardware problem? As far as I know, all android devices with 2.2 or higher have gles2.0 support, so it shouldn't be a software problem, but then again, you never know. You'll just have to comment out parts of your shader until you find the problem area and try to work around it.

Comment: are you sure `r`, `g` and `b` are written in every case in your shader? What happens if you try to init them? (like `float r = 0.0;`, etc.)